# What is Azure SQL Database automatically grows rates

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

On a normal SQL server we can tell it how to grow.  The default is 10% each time, so the database grows by 10% its current size. Do we have any insight on how the Azure SQL database is growing other than it grows automatically?

Azure SQL server would allow us to configure the database to grow in fixed chunks e.g. 20 MB?

thanks,
sakaldeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell, T-SQL, CLI. the portal to increase or decrease the maximum size of a database but Azure SQL Database does not support setting autogrow. You can vote for this feature to be available in the future on [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/36227788-support-auto-grow-for-single-database) URL.

If you run the following query on the database, you will see the growth is set to 2048 KB.

```
SELECT name, growth
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue I am facing is 'the actual data is very low but the DBs have allocated much higher storage space. If we don't shrink the DB regularly then it hits the limit. Not sure, why the DB is allocating that much space. e.g. DB has 4GB data but allocated space is 15GB.

Comment: If the max size is the concern, you can set the max allowed size for each data and log file when you set the growth rate.

Comment: @Sakaldeep This behavior may be related to index fragmentation as explained here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2013/07/27/fragmentation-in-sql-azure/

Comment: @Sakaldeep defrag indexes regularly to keep database size under control.